# Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.HibernateException: Missing column

Tags: java, sql-server, eclipse, hibernate

**Expected result:** how to print data from college role like i shared a screen shot link

Screen shot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSNQO.jpg
project structure: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UkOGY.jpg

Working on simple login and show user type data
where I created a hibernate project in eclipse juno 
I am using 2 classes 
1) College_UserLogin
2) College_Role

and I am trying to get data from 2nd class for the usertype (say student) USING THE COMMON KEY 'RoleID' mentioned in both classes.
 but I am getting this exception and I am stuck,

**Stacktrace**

> Initial SessionFactory creation
>   failed.org.hibernate.HibernateException: Missing column:
>   college_UserLogin in CERPDevNew.dbo.College_Role

**NOTE:** College_UserLogin is table not column but compiler is understanding it as column THIS IS MY PROBLEM

```
    @Entity

    @Table(name = "College_Role")

    //@Inheritance(strategy = javax.persistence.InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)

    //@DiscriminatorValue("College_Role")

    //@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="RoleID")

    public class College_Role implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 9182318500460817975L;

        @Id

        //@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)

        //@OneToOne(mappedBy="collegeRole")

        //@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="roleID")

        //@JoinColumn(name="roleID",referencedColumnName="roleID", unique= true, nullable=true, updatable = false, insertable = false)

        @JoinColumn(name="roleID",unique= true, nullable=false, insertable=false, updatable=false)

        public College_UserLogin college_UserLogin;

         public College_UserLogin getCollege_UserLogin() {

              return college_UserLogin;

            }

            public void setCollege_UserLogin(College_UserLogin college_UserLogin) {

              this.college_UserLogin = college_UserLogin;

            }



        @Column(name="RoleID")
        private int roleID;

    ://body

    **College_UserLogin.java**


    @Entity

    @Table(name = "College_UserLogin")

    //@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)

    //@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "College_UserLogin", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)

    public class College_UserLogin implements Serializable {


        private static final long serialVersionUID = 6304741905092879739L;

        @Id

        //@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)

        //@AttributeOverride(name="roleID", column=@Column(name="roleID"))

        // @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="College_UserLogin")

    //  @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn

        //@JoinColumn(name="roleID",referencedColumnName="role_ID", unique= true, nullable=true, updatable = false, insertable = false)


        private College_Role college_Role;

        public College_Role getCollege_Role() {

            return college_Role;

          }


        public void setCollege_Role(College_Role college_Role) {

            this.college_Role = college_Role;

          }


        public College_UserLogin(){

        }
    //body
```

**UPDATED** **HibernateUtil class**

```
public class HibernateUtil {
private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();
private static ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;
private static Configuration configuration;

**added entity manager factory and entity manager**

static EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("Rest-WS");
static EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();


/* All  SQL, DML entities must be registered */
public static void registerBeans() {
    configuration.addAnnotatedClass(College_UserLogin.class);
    configuration.addAnnotatedClass(College_Role.class);
}

    private static final SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        try {
            configuration = new Configuration();
            configuration.configure();
            registerBeans();

        serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();

        return configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
    }
    catch (Throwable ex) {
        // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed
        System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);

    }
}





public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    //these line i have added//     em.getTransaction().begin();


      College_UserLogin college_UserLogin = new College_UserLogin();
              em.persist(college_UserLogin);


      College_Role college_Role = new College_Role();
    //  college_Role.setName("dept name");
      college_UserLogin.setCollege_Role(college_Role);


      em.flush();
            //up to here these lines i have added// 

    HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();

    //Changes i made 
    Configuration cfg=new Configuration();  
        cfg.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");  

        Session session=sessionFactory.openSession();  

    //   Query query=session.createQuery("select * from College_UserLogin where UserID='ATME.admin'");  
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<College_UserLogin> list= (List<College_UserLogin> )session.createQuery("from College_UserLogin where userid='atme.admin' ").list();


        Iterator<College_UserLogin> itr=list.iterator();  
       // while(itr.hasNext()){  
            //College_UserLogin clg_login = null;
        College_UserLogin clg_login=itr.next();  
         System.out.println(clg_login.getUserID() + itr.next() +" "+ clg_login.getEmailID() + itr.next());  
         College_Role clg_role =clg_login.getCollege_Role();  ;
         System.out.println(" "+  
                 clg_role.getRoleDescription() + itr.next() +" "+clg_role.getSuperiorHeirarchy() + itr.next());   

//these lines i have added//
      System.out.println("success");

    em.getTransaction().commit();
    em.close();
    emf.close();

}

    }
```

**Complete Stack trace**

```
Sep 30, 2015 12:28:03 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version <clinit>

INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.1.Final}

Sep 30, 2015 12:28:03 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion

INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.0.0.Final}

Sep 30, 2015 12:28:03 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>

INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found

Sep 30, 2015 12:28:03 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider

INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist

Sep 30, 2015 12:28:03 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configure

INFO: HHH000043: Configuring from resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml

Sep 30, 2015 12:28:03 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration 
getConfigurationInputStream

INFO: HHH000040: Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml

Sep 30, 2015 12:28:04 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration doConfigure

INFO: HHH000041: Configured SessionFactory: null

Sep 30, 2015 12:28:04 PM 

org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderI
mpl configure

INFO: HHH000402: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)

Sep 30, 2015 12:28:04 PM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure

INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 100

Sep 30, 2015 12:28:04 PM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure

INFO: HHH000006: Autocommit mode: true

Sep 30, 2015 12:28:04 PM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure

INFO: HHH000401: using driver [com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver] at 

URL [jdbc:sqlserver://172.18.1.30;Database=CERPDevNew;]
Sep 30, 2015 12:28:04 PM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure

INFO: HHH000046: Connection properties: {user=Sa, password=****, autocommit=true}

Sep 30, 2015 12:28:04 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>

INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect
Sep 30, 2015 12:28:04 PM 
org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator initiateService

INFO: HHH000268: Transaction strategy: org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransactionFactory

Sep 30, 2015 12:28:04 PM 

org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory <init>

INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory

Sep 30, 2015 12:28:04 PM org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version <clinit>

INFO: HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.1.2.Final

Sep 30, 2015 12:28:04 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaValidator validate

INFO: HHH000229: Running schema validator

Sep 30, 2015 12:28:04 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaValidator validate

INFO: HHH000102: Fetching database metadata

Sep 30, 2015 12:28:04 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>

INFO: HHH000261: Table found: CERPDevNew.dbo.College_Role

Sep 30, 2015 12:28:04 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>

INFO: HHH000037: Columns: [stafftype, isactive, superiorheirarchy, roleid, roledescription]

Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.HibernateException: Missing column: college_UserLogin in CERPDevNew.dbo.College_Role

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

    at com.orcta.dao.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:40)

    at com.orcta.dao.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:17)

Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Missing column: college_UserLogin in CERPDevNew.dbo.College_Role

    at org.hibernate.mapping.Table.validateColumns(Table.java:275)

    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.validateSchema(Configuration.java:1268)

    at 

org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaValidator.validate(SchemaValidator.java:155)

    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:453)

    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1737)

    at com.orcta.dao.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:35)

    ... 1 more
```

Thanks in advance. it will be great help to a beginner in advanced java

Comment: For starters, can you format the code properly, it looks so horrible, and post the stacktrace as well, not just one line of error.

Comment: No, you did not create a JPA project. You created a HIBERNATE project. This is the Hibernate API. You have no EntityManagerFactory or EntityManager.

Comment: Sorry and thanks for the valuable answer. will add entity manager factory in hibernate util and i will update the post with stack trace i am getting.

Comment: You can configure hibernate for updating your schema in persistence.xml. <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>. Use "update" only in development environment ; for production, "validate".

Comment: @Andre thank you for the reply, i already did Update before but friend suggested that i should use validate, cuz i might alter the company's database. right now 'validate' i am going with. so, to display the college_role data, should i change it to update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@PiyushSoni You must not to comment @OneToOne and @JoinColumn annotations! Cause of Hibernate thinks that it is just a column (It must be association by a foreign key). You must add @OneToOne and @JoinColumn annotations in College_UserLogin class, and add   @OneToOne with "mappedBy" in College_Role class. With this annotations you will have a foreign key field in College_UserLogin linked to College_Role.

If you want to have foreign keys in College_UserLogin  and College_Role you must add @OneToOne and @JoinColumn annotations in College_UserLogin class, and add @OneToOne and @JoinColumn annotations  in College_Role class.

I have prepared an example for you. It uses  [User class](https://github.com/v-ladynev/fluent-hibernate-mysql/blob/master/src/com/github/fluent/hibernate/example/mysql/persistent/User.java) (analogue of your College_UserLogin) and [UserAddress class](https://github.com/v-ladynev/fluent-hibernate-mysql/blob/master/src/com/github/fluent/hibernate/example/mysql/persistent/UserAddress.java) (analogue of your College_Role calss).  Please, see annotations on methods User.getAddress() and UserAddress.getUser().

Comment: Billion thanks for such Illustrative way to explain. will follow it and notify for same. actually this was the point that i dont know how to use annotations properly. now i got it.. :)

Comment: @PiyushSoni You are welcome. And, please, please, please don't use "_" in Java class names and field names. And I will be glad if you try to play with [fluent-hibernate library](https://github.com/v-ladynev/fluent-hibernate) cause of i need feedback of using it. :)

Comment: cant help it with "_" , its defined in db as it is see below in comment i have given snapshot of db.

Comment: @PiyushSoni Please, use @Column(name="f_some_column") to refer to columns in DB. And you can use a name strategy to autonaming columns and tables. And you don't need use the class name "College_Role" because you specify a table name in  @Table(name = "College_Role")

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't using  @JoinColumn annotation without 
@OneToMany (or @OneToOne).

P.S. Your session factory initialization will not work properly for Hibernate 5. Try to use [fluent-hibernate](https://github.com/v-ladynev/fluent-hibernate) for factory initialization and doing simply requests. A working simply example using Hibernate and MySQL you can find [here](https://github.com/v-ladynev/fluent-hibernate-mysql). Feel free to ask me anything about this library on GitHub.

Comment: sure but after commenting join column i am getting_____  Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: **Invalid column name 'college_Role'**

Comment: college_Role is name in DB or field in class. You should write field name if not using HQL

Comment: @levvy  that 2 classes i am using is table in db, i generated .java formats for that. :)

Comment: @Levvy My friend, this guy uses "college_Role" for a Java class field name. For a field name, Carl!

Comment: There is no db table explained so I though he wrote bad table. My bad

Comment: @Levvy It is not your mistake. Cause anybody would think the same. It is improperly naming. But it is study why we should using properly naming.

Comment: @ levvy and @ v.ladynev  Here are 2 tables are defined and their primary keys http://imgur.com/qBvgtt0 i have to follow both using common role id key.

Comment: @PiyushSoni Which tables exactly?

Comment: @v.ladynev College_Role and College_UserLogin tables

Comment: @PiyushSoni Please, use a notation "f_user_display_name" for database column names and use "userDisplayName" for Java class field names. With a "f_" prefix you avoid a lot of problems. And use "f_pid" (or "f_id") for primary keys. You don't really need "UserID" and "RoleID". The main distinction of the professional development — is properly naming. :)

Comment: @v.ladynev a big thanks for reference, now when i did this in college_role class - @JoinColumn(name="f_id",referencedColumnName="f_id", unique= true, nullable=true, updatable = false, insertable = false)... it is giving me error-- IdentifierGenerationException: ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save(): com.orcta.jpa.College_UserLogin ... dont know how to proceed with this

Comment: @PiyushSoni Please, just @JoinColumn(name="f_college_role_id"). Don't use name "f_id" because It is an other table id. You must set annotations  "@Id", "@GeneratedValue" on id fields to auto generate ids. You can stream your working with Hibernate on [livecoding.tv](https://www.livecoding.tv/). And me or others will help you. My stream [https://www.livecoding.tv/ladynev/](https://www.livecoding.tv/ladynev/).